# How to make document.querySelector accept div id as parameter?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have this function:

```
document.querySelector(".myDivClass");
```

Which accepts a div css class as parameter. How to make it accept a div id as parameter instead?

Comment: Use the css selector for id, just as you did with class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelector("#myDivId");

or

document.getElementById("myDivId");
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can read there:
[CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), just replace dot with '#'. If this is your div:

```
<div id="abc" ></div>
```

then your selector would be `document.querySelector("#abc");`